# Modelsummary: Different formats for estimates and statistics

Tags: r, format, modelsummary

First of all thanks to the creator of the modelsummary package -- very useful!

I have a question about different `fmt` for statistic and estimates? Here is a reprex:

```
    url <- 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv'
dat <- read.csv(url)
models <- list(
  "OLS 1"     = lm(Donations ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "Poisson 1" = glm(Donations ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat),
  "OLS 2"     = lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "Poisson 2" = glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat),
  "OLS 3"     = lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat)
)
modelsummary(models)
modelsummary(models, output = "flextable", estimate=glue_col("{estimate}{stars}"),
             statistic = 'statistic', stars = c('*' = .1, '**' = .05, '***'=0.01))
```

How can I make the t stats under the coefficients have 2 significant digits and the estimates 3? So that the first coefficient-stat pair would be:
7948.667
(2078.27)

I have perused the documentation but haven't found the answer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: The `fmt` argument now accepts a named list like: `list(estimate = 3, p.value = 4)`

As of version 0.9.4 there is not a *direct* way to achieve this with
just he `fmt` argument or `glue` strings.

However, it is quite easy to leverage the `tidy_custom` and
`glance_custom` mechanisms [described on the `modelsummary`
website](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-i-)
to do just about any post-processing on your estimates and statistics.
This gives users infinite possibilities to customize the output
format.

For example,

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(broom)

tidy_custom.lm <- function(x) {
    out <- broom::tidy(x)
    out$statistic <- sprintf("%.2f", out$statistic)
    out$estimate <- sprintf("%.3f", out$estimate)
    return(out)
}

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, mtcars)

modelsummary(mod, statistic = "statistic", stars = TRUE)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 10.790* |
|  | (2.12) |
| hp | -0.052*** |
|  | (-5.57) |
| drat | 4.698*** |
|  | (3.94) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.741 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.723 |
| AIC | 169.5 |
| BIC | 175.4 |
| Log.Lik. | -80.752 |
| F | 41.522 |

**Note:** ^^ + p < 0.1, * p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001

I opened [an issue on Github.](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/422) Feel free to post there if you want to
contribute to the conversation.

Comment: This works! This is a great example of how to use broom and custom methods for newbies like me. Thank you!