# Modelsummary: Different formats for estimates and extra rows from add_rows

Tags: r, modelsummary

This question is similar in spirit to [Modelsummary: Different formats for estimates and statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389828/modelsummary-different-formats-for-estimates-and-statistics), but concerns the formatting for "additional rows" created with the `add_rows` function of the (excellent) `modelsummary` package. As far as I can tell, these cannot be formatted in a similar manner (though hopefully I'm not missing something basic!). Here's a simple reproducible example.

```
set.seed(03222022)
N <- 10^4
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- 0.000002*x + rnorm(N)

modelsummary(lm(y ~ x),
             fmt = 5,
             add_rows = tibble("term" = "Number of clusters",
                               "value" = 1000),
             output = "markdown")
```

Produces:

```
|                   |  Model 1   |
|:------------------|:----------:|
|(Intercept)        |  0.00062   |
|                   | (0.01005)  |
|x                  |  -0.00885  |
|                   | (0.01007)  |
|Num.Obs.           |   10000    |
|R2                 |   0.000    |
|R2 Adj.            |   0.000    |
|AIC                |  28491.0   |
|BIC                |  28512.6   |
|Log.Lik.           | -14242.496 |
|F                  |   0.772    |
|Number of clusters | 1000.00000 |
```

I could, of course, wrap the 1000 in quotation marks and print it as a character as a quick fix (and more generally, print these values as characters in my practical case---where I'm adding an unrecognized goodness of fit statistic manually). For example, I'm doing something like so to avoid the issue:

```
clusters <- sample(1:1000, N, replace = TRUE)
z <- rnorm(N)
df <- cbind.data.frame(y, x, z, clusters)

m1 <- lm_robust(y ~ x,
          clusters = clusters,
          data = df)

m2 <- lm_robust(y ~ z,
                clusters = clusters,
                data = df)

models <- list(m1, m2)

modelsummary(models,
             fmt = 5,
             add_rows = as_tibble(t(
               as.character(sapply(models, function(x) x$nclusters)))) %>%
               add_column(term = "Number of clusters") %>%
               relocate(term),
             output = "markdown")
```

But I wonder if there's a better way to do this? I really like how it works with `gof_map`, where I can add a formatting function like so: `"fmt" = function(x) format(round(x, 2), big.mark=",")`.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `fmt` argument only works for estimates and statistics, and the `gof_map` argument only works for goodness-of-fit statistics that are extracted automatically by `modelsummary`.

Your idea is interesting, and I tried to think about what kind of user-interface could be used to achieve this. However, all the ideas I came up with were way less elegant than the ultra simple base `R` code I paste below.

If you have a better idea for a user-interface, feel free to [propose it on Github.](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary)

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(estimatr)

set.seed(03222022)
N <- 10^4
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- 0.000002*x + rnorm(N)

clusters <- sample(1:1000, N, replace = TRUE)
z <- rnorm(N)
df <- cbind.data.frame(y, x, z, clusters)

models <- list(
    lm_robust(y ~ x, clusters = clusters, data = df),
    lm_robust(y ~ z, clusters = clusters, data = df))

f <- function(x) format(x$nclusters, big.mark = ",")
ar <- data.frame("Number of Clusters", lapply(models, f))
modelsummary(models,
             add_rows = ar,
             output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 0.001 | 0.000 |
|  | (0.010) | (0.010) |
| x | -0.009 |  |
|  | (0.010) |  |
| z |  | 0.016 |
|  |  | (0.010) |
| Num.Obs. | 10000 | 10000 |
| R2 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| Std.Errors | by: clusters | by: clusters |
| Number of Clusters | 1,000 | 1,000 |

##### With two statistics:

```r
f <- function(x) c(format(x$nclusters, big.mark = ","), "other stuff")
ar <- data.frame(c("Number of Clusters", "Junk"), lapply(models, f))
modelsummary(models,
             add_rows = ar,
             output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 0.001 | 0.000 |
|  | (0.010) | (0.010) |
| x | -0.009 |  |
|  | (0.010) |  |
| z |  | 0.016 |
|  |  | (0.010) |
| Num.Obs. | 10000 | 10000 |
| R2 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| Std.Errors | by: clusters | by: clusters |
| Number of Clusters | 1,000 | 1,000 |
| Junk | other stuff | other stuff |

Comment: Thanks Vincent! Much appreciated. I'll give it a think, but I think you're right that the way to go is to simply go through `add_rows`. I love `modelsummary`, btw. Definitely the best table making package I've worked with!